# (-215:Assertion failed) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function 'copyTo'

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get the dominant colors from my screen with the following code:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

#include <X11/extensions/XShm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


#include <time.h>
#define FPS(start) (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / (clock()-start))


struct ScreenShot{
    ScreenShot(uint x, uint y, uint width, uint height):
               x(x), y(y), width(width), height(height){

        display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
        root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

        XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &window_attributes);
        screen = window_attributes.screen;
        ximg = XShmCreateImage(display, DefaultVisualOfScreen(screen), DefaultDepthOfScreen(screen), ZPixmap, NULL, &shminfo, width, height);

        shminfo.shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, ximg->bytes_per_line * ximg->height, IPC_CREAT|0777);
        shminfo.shmaddr = ximg->data = (char*)shmat(shminfo.shmid, 0, 0);
        shminfo.readOnly = false;
        if(shminfo.shmid < 0)
            puts("Fatal shminfo error!");;
        Status s1 = XShmAttach(display, &shminfo);
        printf("XShmAttach() %s\n", s1 ? "success!" : "failure!");

        init = true;
    }

    void operator() (cv::Mat& cv_img){
        if(init)
            init = false;

        XShmGetImage(display, root, ximg, 0, 0, 0x00ffffff);
        cv_img = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC4, ximg->data);
    }

    ~ScreenShot(){
        if(!init)
            XDestroyImage(ximg);

        XShmDetach(display, &shminfo);
        shmdt(shminfo.shmaddr);
        XCloseDisplay(display);
    }

    Display* display;
    Window root;
    XWindowAttributes window_attributes;
    Screen* screen;
    XImage* ximg;
    XShmSegmentInfo shminfo;

    int x, y, width, height;

    bool init;
};

int main(){
    ScreenShot screen(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
    cv::Mat img;

    for(uint i;; ++i){
        double start = clock();

        screen(img);

        if(!(i & 0b111111))
            printf("fps %4.f  spf %.4f\n", FPS(start), 1 / FPS(start));
            break;
    }
    // Serialize, float
    cv::Mat data = img.reshape(1, img.total());
    data.convertTo(data, CV_32F);
    // Perform k-Means
    int k = 10;
    std::vector<int> labels;
    cv::Mat3f centers;
    cv::kmeans(data, k, labels, cv::TermCriteria(), 1, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,   centers);

    // Make a poster! (Clustering)
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)labels.size(); ++i) {
        data.at<float>(i, 0) = centers.at<float>(labels[i], 0);
        data.at<float>(i, 1) = centers.at<float>(labels[i], 1);
        data.at<float>(i, 2) = centers.at<float>(labels[i], 2);
    }
    // Un-Serialize, un-float
    cv::Mat destination = data.reshape(3, img.rows);
    destination.convertTo(img, CV_8UC3);
    std::sort(centers.begin(), centers.end(),
            [](const cv::Vec3f &a, const cv::Vec3f &b) -> bool
            { return a[0] + a[1] + a[2] > b[0] + b[1] + b[2]; }
        );

    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it with:
`` gcc screena.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` -lX11 -lXext -Ofast -mfpmath=both -march=native -m64 -funroll-loops -mavx2 -lstdc++ -g ``

The error seems to be in line 85 and the output is:

```
➜ ./a.out
XShmAttach() success!
fps 26316  spf 0.0000
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.5) /build/opencv/src/opencv-4.5.5/modules/core/src/copy.cpp:320: error: (-215:Assertion failed) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function 'copyTo'

[1]    95765 abort (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

Any idea on how to make it work??

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question because this is my first time using opencv with cpp, but i tried a lot of things and I cant get my code to work. Thanks :)

Comment: The assertion seems to be complaining about the number of channels of your matrices. You seem to copy matrix data from another, and the number of channels do not match.

Comment: How can it be solved? @stateMachine

Comment: check the number of channels of the involved matrices. add that information to your question. -- I don't see any use of `copyTo` in your code. where exactly does this assertion fail? learn about debugging techniques, such as using a debugger to single-step through your code. -- line numbers sadly don't mean anything on stack overflow, because the code isn't annotated with line numbers. you'll have to point that line out specifically. -- convertTo can't add channels. make sure you aren't trying to do that.

Comment: to use kmeans, you need a single channel (4 cols here) Mat, each pixel on it's own row. and maybe you should also strip the unused 4th channel before